# Fix line spacing in word with '-' character

Tags: microsoft-word

Is there a way to fix linespacing in word **correctly** ?

Using this method doesn't really fix it : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-line-spacing-in-word-04ada056-b8ef-4b84-87dd-5d7c28a85712

As you can see there are still some spaces and to fix that I have to insert some '-' manually to cut off some words.

[image]

This is how I manually changed it and it looks much better :

[image]

Is there a way to do this automatically and not have to insert '_' manually everywhere.

Latex does this automatically but I have to write this document in Word.

Comment: Layout -> Hyphenation. Set it to Automatic.

Comment: The line spacing in each example is identical. Hyphenation forces the *word spacing* to be different.

Comment: See also https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/controlling-word-spacing-in-paragraphs/2d5ac5b9-06d9-44be-9341-198488c28e59

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean hyphenation, and in Word 2016? You can turn that on in the paragraph settings: Home pane -> Paragraph -> Paragraph settings (the tiny square/arrow at the bottom right)

[image: word 2016 paragraph options]

I suspect this is related to the proofing language you set (Review pane -> Language), so make sure that corresponds to the language you write in, even if you're not using autocorrect.